# Geometric realizations of cluster categories of non-simply-laced types

Tags: rt.representation-theory, derived-categories, cluster-algebras

Geometric realizations of cluster categories of simply-laced types are studied in the following papers.

1. Philippe Caldero, Frédéric Chapoton, and Ralf. Schiffler, [Quivers with relations arising from clusters ($A_n$ case)](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401316).
2. Ralf Schiffler, [A geometric model for cluster categories of type $D_n$](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608264).
3. Lisa Lamberti, [Combinatorial model for the cluster categories of type $E$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.0549).

I didn't find papers which studied geometric realizations of cluster categories of non-simply-laced types. Have this problem been studied? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

The main author I am aware of working on this problem is Demonet, see

1. [Cluster algebras and preprojective algebras : the non simply-laced case](https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.4098)
2. [Categorification of skew-symmetrizable cluster algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.1633)
3. [Mutations of group species with potentials and their representations. Applications to cluster algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5078)

There is also an earlier paper of Dong Yang which I have not read:

4. [Non-simply-laced Clusters of Finite Type via Frobenius Morphism](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608114)

To my understanding, all of these papers use some form of folding construction to reduce to the skew-symmetric case. This is a problem, because there are quivers which cannot be unfolded! See Example 14.4 in

5. [Strongly primitive species with potentials I: Mutations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.3495)

This last paper attempts to provide a partial solution to the problem of categorifying the non-unfoldable case. You might also want to watch [Daniel Labardini-Fragoso's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RD6vo9TsgTc) from Zelevinsky's memorial conference; I thought it provided a very clear overview.